# Javascript code to display a banner not working

Tags: javascript, html, popup

I want to put a banner on my website, when users access the site, just to show some information.

I tried the following solution:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    window.cookieconsent.initialise({
      "palette": {
        "popup": {
          "background": "#237afc"
        },
        "button": {
          "background": "#fff",
          "text": "#237afc"
        }
      },
      "theme": "edgeless",
      "content": {
        "message": "this is some random message i want to show"
      }
    })});
    </script>
```

I can't notice anything wrong here, but it shows no errors and no popup. I just notice a slight delay when accessing the site, nothing else.

Where am i going wrong with this?

Comment: I just put your code in a jsfiddle and it's working :)

Comment: missing https and you've properly already accepted it once so need to go in incoginto or clear cahce

Comment: @JoeWarner There is no need for `https://` using just `//` is perfectly valid.

Comment: interesting thanks! @Nope also good name xD

Comment: @Nope i thought it would work to, but theres nothing appearing... any thought on that?

Comment: If it works in isolation but not when you ad the code to the rest of you application (you mentioned that in the comment on the other answer) then it could be anything. We only see the isolated code.

Comment: i have it in the <head>, if i post all the code there, will it be enough? or you would have to see css and everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is regarding the cookie, if you press "Got it" will set a cookie (cookiecontent_status) and the message will not appear second time. You should clear cookies, or open an incognito tab, will see the message will appear.

Comment: yeah, and that´s what i´m going for... but when i add the code to the rest, nothing happens, and i´m not understanding why